# Keep getting StreamCorruptedException, even though the code is fine

Tags: java, eclipse

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dataFile);
    ObjectInputStream getItem = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    player[0] = (HighScore) getItem.readObject();

    for(int i = 0; i< player.length; i++)
    {
        highscoreinfo.setText("<html>" + highscoreinfo.getText() + "<br>" + player[i]);
        System.out.println(player[i]);

    }

    getItem.close();
```

As seen above, the player[0] line is what gives me the error. Even when I had this inside the loop, it would give me the same error. Keep in mind there is only 1 line of data on the data file, which is why I am only trying to get the console to read the first line
**Edit:** Here's the writing part of the code, as you guys wanted:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dataFile, true);
    ObjectOutputStream saveItem = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);  
    player[intplayernum] = new HighScore(userName, timePlayed, totalwords, timecount.getText());
    saveItem.writeObject(player[intplayernum].toString());

    for(int i = 0; i<= intplayernum; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(player[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Player score written to file.");
    saveItem.close();
     GameFrame.setVisible(false);
     GameFrame.dispose();
     askNameApp();
     intplayernum++;
```

Comment: I assume the problem is the writing part of the code.

Comment: How did you write the data to the file? Did you change anything in the `HighScore` class between reading and writing?

Comment: The writing happens each time a button is pressed, appending to the already existing data file. The file itself shows all my data in one line, which is fine, but it cannot seem to read it

Comment: While (most probably) not your immediate problem - you are writing a `toString()` (which is a `String`, possibly custom made for human readability) and trying to read `Highscore`. I'd guess that would throw a ClassCastException, if you got that far.

Comment: You're appending to the file every time you write but only reading the first entry, have you tried deleting the file to start fresh instead of repeatedly trying to read the first thing you wrote to the file?